# Новое подписание apk

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk

После подписания апк с использованием ключей v1 + v2 и загрузки его в маркет на странице приложения вижу "Приложение несовместимо с вашими устройствами." 
Если пробовать запустить уже подписанное апк на телефоне, то все работает нормально, но после загрузка в маркет его невозможно оттуда скачать. 
В приложении не используется никаких разрешений.
Приложение платное, думал проблема в стране, но другие платные приложения мне доступны((
как можно исправить эту ситуацию?

package - com.airplanes.countrybycountry